# Loading notification in windows mobile 6.5 (Spinner)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile-6.5, motorola-emdk

I'm developing a WM6.5 application on [Motorola ES400](http://support.symbol.com/support/browse.do?WidgetName=BROWSE_PRODUCT&TaxoName=SG_SupportGoals&BROWSE_PRODUCT.isProductTaxonomy=true&BROWSE_PRODUCT.NodeId=SG_ES400_1_2&BROWSE_PRODUCT.thisPageUrl=%2Fproduct%2Fproducts.do&id=m4&BROWSE_PRODUCT.TaxoName=SG_SupportGoals&NodeType=leaf&NodeName=ES400&document=DT_PRODUCTMANUALS_1_1&BROWSE_PRODUCT.NodeType=leaf&NodeId=SG_ES400_1_2&AppContext=AC_ProductPage&param_document=sp) and need a notification for users to appear when my application is busy doing something 
Searching in [EMDK](http://support.symbol.com/support/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=13209&sliceId=&dialogID=246856292&stateId=1%200%20246858314).
I've searched in the Help of EMDK and found the **Symbol.MT2000.UserInterface.Spinner** class 
but in calling of this class I've a null exception error
this is the code :

```
`
Symbol.MT2000.UserInterface.Spinner sp = new Symbol.MT2000.UserInterface.Spinner();
//This is a delegate of the DeleteAll function
sp.BeginInvoke(DeleteAll);

`
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your null reference could be solved by adding the `new` keyword, something like this:

```
Symbol.MT2000.UserInterface.Spinner sp = new Symbol.MT2000.UserInterface.Spinner();
```

Just curious, could you not just set the cursor to the wait cursor and achieve the same effect?

```
Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
```

Comment: no cause it's a windows mobile app and in those devices the cursor should not be on as non-professionals will work on it so i need the spinner class,And the new keyword is written already but it was my fault writing the thread

Comment: Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor; works totally fine for me.